# Firebase GetValueAsync() if task.result doesnt exist it doesnt execute code below

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function on a Unity game that works fine on computer but it doenst on mobile devices.
The problem is the bool snap is going to be false the code doesnt execute any line below `DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;`. But if `DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;` returns 1 result, it works fine.

```
void CheckUser()
{
    reference.Child("Stars").Child("Users").Child(login).LimitToFirst(1)
        .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    info.text = "falha";
                }
                else if (task.IsCompleted)
                {

                    //info.text = task.Result.ToString();
                    DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                    //info.text = snapshot.ToString();


                    bool snap = snapshot.Exists;
                    info.text = snap.ToString();


                    if (snap)
                    {
                        info.text = "login existente, selecione outro sff";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        info.text = "falha 4 ";
                        writeLogin();
                    }
                    // Do something with snapshot...
                }
                else
                {
                    info.text = "falha 3 ";
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Why dont you await the task `var result = await CheckUser()`; if you dont await the task ur UI thread hang until it will complete. This awkward for a phone

Comment: I don't really get the problem

Comment: do you see the code after the line DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;, i thing because of the time it takes to end it it goes over all the code after it without executing it

Answer (score 0):

```
void CheckUser()
    {


        reference.Child("Stars").Child("Users")
            .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    info.text = "Verifique a Internet e tente de novo";
                }
                else if (task.IsCompleted)
                {

                    //info.text = task.Result.ToString();
                    IDictionary snapshot = (IDictionary) task.Result.Value;



                    bool snap = false;
                    if (snapshot[login]!= null)
                    {
                        snap = true;
                    }

                    Debug.Log(snap.ToString());


                    if (snap)
                    {
                        info.text = "login existente, selecione outro sff";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //info.text = "falha 4 ";
                        writeLogin();
                    }
                    // Do something with snapshot...
                }
                else
                {
                    info.text = "Verifique a Internet e tente de novo";
                }
            });
    }
```